# Interpretation of log likelihood and covariate significance in Cox regression

Tags: regression

Another newbie question here (probably piece of cake for you guys).

When I run a Cox Regression and one of my covariates come out as significant:

```
                                                    95,0% CI for Exp(B)
        B       SE      Wald    df  Sig.    Exp(B)  Lower   Upper
risk    2,224   1,107   4,036   1   ,045    9,244   1,056   80,950
<5 covariates removed for clarity>
```

But my Omnibus Tests of Model Coefficients(a) isn't significant. Change from previous step: Chi-square=10,290. df=6. Sig.=0,113.

Does this mean my model is simply too bad to use for anything? Can I say anything credible about my data after running this analysis?

Thanks for any clues that'll take me closer to the beauty of applied statistics... ;)

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credibility depends on context and you've not offered any. If the other 5 degrees of freedom are in the model for good reasons but you aren't particularly interested in estimating the effects, only interested in the impact of "risk", then you may have something interesting but the really wide confidence interval prevents me from applying the label "credible". However, the likelihood ratio test for the addition of "risk" to the model would be a more solid estimate of its effect independent of the other covariates. Your Wald test is fairly borderline.

Comment: I'm not really interested in the effect of the other coravirates, I just put them in the model to control for the effect they have. If I understand you correctly, my statistic "indicates a genuine effect even though it is only borderline significant"?

Comment: Hardly. I would not accept that as a fair paraphrase of what I said. I say one would first need to do a LRT examination before doing further discussion of whether the borderline Wald test even met conventional standards for significance. And  I think the work "genuine" is a far reach in the absence of better context.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me. And I'm sorry for the delayed response. I've separated the covariates in 2 blocks in the analysis. The first block contains the 5 covariates I want to control for, the second block contains only the 'risk' covariate. In Block 2 I get a 'Change from previous block'-statistic: Chi-square=6,298, df=1, sig=0,012. Doesn't this mean that the second changed the model significantly? Is this what you mean by Likelihood Ratio Test?

Comment: It's a bit hazy on this side of the crystal ball interface, since you are using some sort of software that has it's own particular terminology. It sounds as though there was a change in the 2*log-likelihood of 6.298 when risk was added. Given the limits of what you have offered,  it appears the evidence in favor of "risk" (whatever it might be) being associated with shorter survival time is considerably stronger than was indicated by the Wald test.